# Quad integration returning only 0.0 within tkinter mainloop program, executes fine as code fragment on its own

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, scipy, quad

So I'm working on a radiance to apparent temperature calculator tool to integrate into a data analysis program with lots of different functions. My "test code" ran fine on it's own outside of my main program and gave correct results.
Code that works:

```
from numpy import arange, exp, vectorize, size, zeros, seterr, where, log10, all
from scipy.constants import h,c,k,pi
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.integrate import quad


def planck_l(l, T):
    c1 = 2*h*c**2
    c2 = h*c / k
    M = (c1/l**5) * (1 / (exp(c2/(l*T))-1))
    return M


def planck_p(l, T):
    c1 = 2*pi*c
    c2 = h*c / k
    M = (c1/(pi*l**4)*(1/(exp(c2/(l*T))-1)))
    return M


def integrand(planck, lband, rband, T):
    return quad(planck, lband, rband, args=T)[0]


def getRadiance(planck,lband,rband,T):
    int_planck = vectorize(integrand)
    return int_planck(planck,lband,rband,T)


def rad2t(rad, l, r):
    temps = arange(0, 5000)
    radiance = []
    for t in temps:
        radiance.append(integrand(planck_l, l/1e6, r/1e6, t)/100/100)
    f = interp1d(radiance, temps)
    T = f(rad)
    return T
```

However when I integrate this code into my main tkinter GUI loop, the integrand function I've defined only returns values of 0.0. Code that doesn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import sys
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
import struct
import cv2
import csv
from scipy.constants import h, c, k, pi
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import bigfloat


def planck_l(l, T):
    c1 = 2*h*c**2
    c2 = h*c / k
    M = (c1/l**5) * (1 / (np.exp(c2/(l*T))-1))
    return M


def planck_p(l, T):
    c1 = 2*pi*c
    c2 = h*c / k
    M = (c1/(pi*l**4)*(1/(np.exp(c2/(l*T))-1)))
    return M


def integrand(planck, lband, rband, T):
    return quad(planck, lband, rband, args=T)[0]


def getRadiance(planck,lband,rband,T):
    int_planck = np.vectorize(integrand)
    return int_planck(planck, lband, rband, T)


def rad2T(rad, l, r):
    temps = np.arange(0, 5000)
    radiance = []
    for t in temps:
        radiance.append(integrand(planck_l, l/1e6, r/1e6, t)/100/100)
    f = interp1d(radiance, temps)
    T = f(rad)
    return T

#.......... other definitions, main window/widget building etc. ...........

def rad_t_conv(self, coor):
    window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    window.geometry(coor[0] + coor[1])
    window.grab_set()

    Label(window, text='Set Wavelength Range (um): ').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    range = StringVar()
    range.set('3-5')
    range_enter = Entry(window, textvariable=range, width=10)
    range_enter.grid(row=1, column=0)
    window.rngsub = tk.Button(window, text='Save', command=lambda: self.submit(range_enter, range))
    window.rngsub.grid(row=2, column=0)

    Label(window, text='Radiance:').grid(row=3, column=0)
    rad = StringVar()
    rad_enter = Entry(window, textvariable=rad, width=10)
    rad_enter.grid(row=4, column=0)
    window.radsub = tk.Button(window, text='Calculate App. Temp', command=lambda: self.combine(self.submit(rad_enter, rad), self.calc_temp(rad.get(), range.get(), t_enter, temp)))
    window.radsub.grid(row=5, column=0)

    Label(window, text='App. Temperature:').grid(row=3, column=1)
    temp = StringVar()
    t_enter = Entry(window, textvariable=temp, width=10)
    t_enter.grid(row=4, column=1)
    window.tempsub = tk.Button(window, text='Calculate Radiance', command=lambda: self.combine(self.submit(t_enter, temp), self.calc_rad(temp.get(), range.get(), rad_enter, rad)))
    window.tempsub.grid(row=5, column=1)

def calc_temp(self, rad, range, temp_ent, temp):
    range = range.split('-')
    rad = float(rad)
    l = float(range[0])
    r = float(range[1])
    T = rad2t(rad, l, r)
    temp.set(str(T))
    self.update_idletasks()

def calc_rad(self, temp, range, rad_ent, rad):
    range = range.split('-')
    l = int(range[0])
    r = int(range[1])
    temp = float(temp)
    radiance = integrand(planck_l, l/1e6, r/1e6, temp)/100/100
    print(radiance)
    rad.set(str(radiance))
    self.update_idletasks()
```

---

I thought it was maybe a rounding issue but utilizing bigfloat had no effect. I'm truly puzzled as to why it would work outside of my main code and then fail in this way when integrated. I've been scouring the rest of my tkinter gui window code for anything that could be effecting it but I'm pretty stumped. Any help, or guesses even, are much appreciated. I can post more of my main code if requested but it's honestly a giant mess since I've been using pyinstaller to compile it into an .exe and it needs to have all non-module functions defined within the same file. To answer @jsbueno, my call to rad_t_conv is from a button in my main window.

```
 self.rad2t_start = tk.Button(self, text='Radiance/Apparent Temp Conversion', command=lambda: self.rad_t_conv(coor))
 self.rad2t_start.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5)
```

Class is defined as such:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
```

And then called as:

```
root = tk.Tk()
w = 700 # width for the Tk root
h = 500 # height for the Tk root
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
app = Application(master=root)
app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

The combine function is:

```
def combine(self, *funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func
```

Comment: Where are your actuall calls to  `rad_t_conv` and Tkinter's mainloop?

Comment: Also, the class declaration, and your `combine` method.

Comment: @jsbueno My calls to `rad_t_conv` are from a button in my master tk window. `self.rad2t_start = tk.Button(self, text='Radiance/Apparent Temp Conversion', command=lambda: self.rad_t_conv(coor))
        self.rad2t_start.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5)` My class declaration is `class Application(tk.Frame)` and calling the mainloop `root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()`

Comment: @jsbueno Oh and my combine function is definied as `def combine(self, *funcs):
        def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for f in funcs:
                f(*args, **kwargs)
        return combined_func`